# Error while changing name "mv: target ‘DGProdAtt_1_20221101101807.xlsx’ is not a directory"

Tags: linux, mv

Hi I am trying to change a file name but it is giving me error as below :
Original filename:`005356209MAINSFTP_005356209DSM_ DGProdAtt_1_2022_11_01_10_18_07.xlsx`

```
mv 005356209MAINSFTP_005356209DSM_ DGProdAtt_1_2022_11_01_10_18_07.xlsx 005356209DSM_005356209MAINSFTP_DGProdAtt_1_20221101101807.xlsx
```

`mv: target ‘DGProdAtt_1_20221101101807.xlsx’ is not a directory`

how to solve the directory error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I see correctly, there is a white space in your file name `005356209MAINSFTP_005356209DSM_ DGProdAtt_1_2022_11_01_10_18_07.xlsx`.
You should always put a backslash ( \ ) before special characters like space in bash. Otherwise bash sees it as a separator between input parameters of the command.

So your correct command will be:

```
mv 005356209MAINSFTP_005356209DSM_\ DGProdAtt_1_2022_11_01_10_18_07.xlsx 005356209DSM_005356209MAINSFTP_DGProdAtt_1_20221101101807.xlsx
```

Note: Always use the **tab key** when you are typing in bash instead of typing the whole file names manually.

Comment: HI Farhad thanks you it works

Comment: @MokanVelan So please mark the post as answer. Thanks